# Как обьеденить java и python, в visual code .sln?

Tags: python, java

я задался вопросом, а как ? Как люди пишут приложение или же программы с играми на 2 и более языках? Я читал что для visual code есть файл .sln но не могу понять как объединить 2 языка и как это называется?

Comment: Просто при написании таким образом программ\игр, не используют 2 языка к ряду для решения одних и тех же задач. Т.е. если мне требуется написать серверную часть игры\программы - я могу воспользоваться Python\Php\Ruby и тд... А для отрисовки например визуальных эффектов я буду пользоваться C#\C++. Но в целом эти ЯП взаимозаменяемы, или вовсе пишут все на одном. Но в целом никто не решает одну и ту же задачу на разных языках в проекте. Могу ошибаться конечно... Ещё проще пример - я могу использовать C++ для написания библиотек, а C# для использовании их в проекте.

Comment: Для visual code нет файла .sln - это файл проекта Visual Studio, а не Visual Studio Code (это очень разные программы/среды разработки). Visual Studio не поддерживает Java, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Объединить конкретно Java и Python можно например с использованием Jython - правда, эта библиотека поддерживает только синтаксис Python 2.7. В целом, обычно есть библиотека-"обертка" над интерпретатором Python для другого языка программирования (или альтернативна реализация интрепретатора, как Jython или Iron Python). Технически взаимодействие кода на разных ЯП называется FFI (Foreign function interface).

Comment: Друзья, спасибо всем, но я так и не могу понять, просто мысль в голову для проекта пришла, java + python, почему такая связка? Мне удобно работать с потоками на питоне, а на джаве у меня приложение, ибо же для как можно написать api или то что поможет связать? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @KeithNaumov ради только потоков нет смысла использовать связку Python + Java.

Answer (score 1):

- [Jython](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Jython) — Python, реализованный на Java.
- [JPype](https://wiki.python.org/moin/JPype) — позволяет Python запускать Java-команды(Стильненько!)
- [Jepp](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Jepp) — Python, встроенный в Java
- [JCC](https://pypi.org/project/JCC/2.12/) — генератор кода C++ для вызова Java из C++/Python.
- [Javabridge](https://pypi.org/project/javabridge/) — пакет для запуска и взаимодействия с JVM от CPython.
- [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/index.html) — позволяет Python запускать java-команды(`ИМХО!` как мне кажется лучший! до сих пор развивающийся вариант).
- [voc](https://voc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) — часть пакета BeeWare . Преобразует код Python в байт-код Java.
- [p2j](https://github.com/chrishumphreys/p2j) — конвертирует код Python в Java. Больше не развивается.

---

- [Как вызвать Python из Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-working-with-python)
- [Integrating Python with Java](https://devm.io/python/integrating-python-with-java-170663#:%7E:text=Python%20is%20an%20object%2Doriented,write%20entire%20applets%20in%20Python.)
- [Ещё немного о вызове Python из Java - stackoverflow En](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration)

---